# Trouble creating multiple copies of folders and altering specific values on a certain line, on a unique file, in each copied folder

Tags: python, terminal

I am trying to create multiple copies of a single folder. Then what I want to do is change some words in a specific line in a specific file, on all folders i.e.:

1. copy folderX -> folder1, folder2, ..., folderN (N could be let's say 200)
2. find file ( the file has a specific extension, for example a .txt file in a folder full of .jpgs')
3. change words, example: sot 1 1 1 -> sot 2 2 2 (each file will have a different new value (one would be sot 2 2 2, the other sot 3 3 3 etc.))

What I have tried so far, first to make a copy of the folder:

1. `for i in {0...200}; do cp -r test/ test_$i; done` (didn't work)
2. `for i in (i=0; i<=200; i++); do cp -r test/ test_$i; done` (worked but not as intended, it sometimes raised errors)

So I figured a workaround in Python,

```
for i in range(3):
    os.system('cp -r orig_test test-%s' % (i))
```

This works like a charm. But when I try to change the words in the files it only displays the contents of the line.

```
"grep -r "sot = 1" 1RWT_HpH-* | xargs sed -i "s/1/2/g"
```

As I told you the line has the form sot 1 1 1 and the value needs to be changed from 1 1 1 to different value on each iteration. The values will be provided from a list.

If it helps I am using Mac OS, maybe that is why some features supposed to be working on Linux don't give the exact same results.

**P.S.** If possible I would prefer an educational answer not a super efficient that does it all in just one line code.

Thank you so very much in advance. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part: to count in a shell, you need to do a little more work. Assuming you are using `bash`, you can do the following (this is very similar to what you tried, but you needed double brackets):

```
 for ((n=0; n<=100; n++))
 do
     cp -r test test_$n
 done
```

Note that shell is quite picky about where you put spaces and newlines. I realise that `man bash` is a long read, but it's worth it if you need to do more of this. 
If you want to experiment, best to put an `echo` in place of the `cp` command, so you can try things without messing up your files:

```
 for ((n=0; n<=100; n++))
 do
     echo $n
 done
```

Regarding your second question: the `grep` will return the line from the file, not just the filename. For that, you need the `-l` flag (that's *ell*, not *one*). So, you can try:

```
grep -lr "sot = 1" 1RWT_HpH-* | xargs sed -i "s/1/2/g"
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply, I'll definetly try the test loop and the man page. My problem actually is that with xargs sed (etc) where I cannot change the values. But I had to write the whole command to make sense.